# Send a php error header if mysql don't work

Tags: php, mysql, header

I have an "uptime monitor" that alert me via email when the site is offline (or more exaclty when it donsen't return a 200 status).

Just wondering if can I set an error with php header in case mysql crash, like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if (!$link) {
 header( 'HTTP/1.0 500 Server error' );
 die( 'Mysql error' );
}
```

or

```
if (mysqli_ping($link)) {
 header( 'HTTP/1.0 500 Server error' );
 die( 'Mysql error' );
}
```

In this way I guess the "uptime monitor" can alert me even if mysql gone away.

Can be a good solution? Which is the best way and what error number should I use?

Comment: `http_response_code(500);`